# Is there any way to move paginator from ngx-datatable to header instead of footer?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

I set up my ngx-datatable with the paginator inside an angular project as below.

```html
    <ngx-datatable class="material" [rows]="rows"...
      [count]="count" [limit]="5" [offset]="0" (page)="setPage($event)">
```

It works and the pagination is shown. But I want to show it in header too, is there anyway I can copy the one from footer and put it in header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it does not have `built-in` option, but based on this [GitHub conversation](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/1125#issuecomment-410724978), you can do it with custom CSS:

```css
.ngx-datatable .datatable-footer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.ngx-datatable .datatable-header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}

.ngx-datatable .datatable-body {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

I just tested it and it still works.